# Standard user can change the Date and Time

Tags: time, date, timezone

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS edition. And now I want that I give full right to my Standard user to change the Time and Date accordingly.

In my system After shutting down the system for a 4-5 hrs reset the time of my system.?
I set the time manually by GUI interface from the administrator account. I set UTC=no in rs5 configuration file. But Problem is same.

Any idea to give the privileges to the Normal user to change the Date n Time?

Answer (score 1):

Not literally the answer you are asking for, but if your system is forgetting the time and / or date, you will probably need a new cmos battery on your motherboard. As [this link](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000239.htm) explains, it sometimes helps to leave the computer on for a long(er) time to see if the battery is charging a bit, so it can remember the time & date a bit longer.

The link also describes how to change the battery.